# compare 2 lists and append values to new list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im beginner in python, trying to return a new list of dictionary v3, when values in List v2 is equal to keys of v1 list of dictionary.
New list of dictionary v3 should contains matched keys with values.

```
v1 = [
    {"Key": "State", "Value": "UP"},
    {"Key": "city", "Value": "bihar"},
    {"Key": "Name", "Value": "Sam"},
    {"Key": "Product", "Value": "cookies"},
    {"Key": "id", "Value": "23"},
    {"Key": "email", "Value": "enim@gmail.com"},
]
v2 = ["Name", "Product", "State", "Name"]
v3 = []
```

The expected output should be

```
v3 = [
    {"Key": "Name", "Value": "Sam"},
    {"Key": "Product", "Value": "cookies"},
    {"Key": "State", "Value": "UP"},
    {"Key": "Name", "Value": "Sam"},
]
```

Below is my code which i tried but code is incomplete

```
for bb in v1:
    if bb['Key'] in v2:
        v3.append({bb['Key']:bb['Value']})
```

Comment: why `{"Key": "Name", "Value": "Sam"}` occurs 2 times in your expected output. Is this intentional or a mistake?

Comment: @VishalSingh IIUC, it's not a mistake. It seems like the OP is iterating over the values of `v2`, and searching the for the dictionary that has each the value equal to `dct['Key']`. So, `'Name'` occurs two times in `v2`, that's why the dictionary appears twice in `v3`.

Comment: its intentional.That is the reason,i didn't choose Dictionary as output.Dictionary wont accepts duplicates.So i want duplicates too in  list of Dictionary as output

Comment: @Mr.Nobody33 Sorry for that. didnt seen yours and scrolling down for other answers. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with list comprehension:

```
v3=[dc for val  in v2 for dc in v1 if val==dc['Key']]
```

Output:

```
v3
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}, {'Key': 'Product', 'Value': 'cookies'}, {'Key': 'State', 'Value': 'UP'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the expected output you need to reverse the loop order, loop over v2 list first, and then check if that key exists in V1.

```
for v in v2:
    for d in v1:
      if d["Key"] == v:
         v3.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your first dict like the following:

```
v1 = {'State': 'UP',
 'city': 'bihar',
'Name': 'Sam',
'Product': 'cookies',
 'id': '23',
 'email': 'enim@gmail.com'}
v2 = ['Name', 'Product', 'State','Name']
v3 = dict()

for x in v2:
    if x in v1:
        print({x: v1.get(x)})
        v3.update({x: v1.get(x)})
```

update adds the record or updates it when the key is available and
{} is another way of constructing dicts

source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) might help.

Try this:

```
[i for i in v1 if i['Key'] in v2]
```

Result:

```
[{'Key': 'State', 'Value': 'UP'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}, {'Key': 'Product', 'Value': 'cookies'}]
```

Speaking of expected v3, I'm not sure why `{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}` appeared twice when that element only appears once in v1. Perhaps typos?

## EDITED

```
[i for j in v2 for i in v1 if i['Key'] == j]
```

result:

```
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}, {'Key': 'Product', 'Value': 'cookies'}, {'Key': 'State', 'Value': 'UP'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Sam'}]
```